# EC2 instance autoscale in different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, region

I'm pretty new to aws and already set up an EC2 Instance running my Node.js Server. I created an AMI and added it to an Auto Scaling Group. Now I want to setup a Load Balancer which has one IP address and has different autoscaling groups in different Regions. It should connect the user to the Region with the lowest delay and consistently send and receive websocket messages from that server.
But all I see in my Settings is the VPC for the European region. Do I have to setup a new VPC? Or is this even possible what I'm trying to do?

Hope somebody can help me out, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do that using Route53. You create your load balances on the regions you want, with their instances, running the same application, and setup route 53 to route the requests based on latency or geolocation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html